# Any good charting solutions for asp.net that can generate charts on server side and push them to the client?

Tags: asp.net, charts

We are getting rid of our flash based charting solutions to help users use our site on IPAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try chardirector 

http://www.advsofteng.com/